# What does the option "Enable Display field" shown when creating a new file field do/mean?

Tags: 8, entities

What does the option *Enable Display field* shown when creating a new file field do/mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will provide you an additional option whether you want to display the attached file or not. As you can see the description provide under that option in following image.

> [image]

Now enabling it, will add `check box option` to content editing layer as you can see in following image.

`Include file in display`

> [image]

So, if you check it will show the file in final display and if you uncheck it will not show the file.

Hence, it provides one extra quick option to author whether they want to show the attached file or not other-wise previously they had to go back and delete entire file from the content and again if they want to put they have to again upload and insert. Here, it is like On-Off Switch.

Comment: I see, but i have added two file fields, one with the checked option and one without it but both are shown when i see the node, even when anonymous o maybe i'm just not understanding what it is for

Comment: Hmmm nevermind, i see it now. Just as you said. Just to be clear, when not checking the option i guess it is forced. Thanks

Comment: @GianniDiFalco When you do not do anything, anything at all, the file will show as normal. But when you check the option `Enable Display filed`, it will add new option `Include file in display` at author level as I mentioned in answer. So now, by default `Include....` option will be checked because we want to show the file, but you have now freedom to un-check.